# Split view into two separate views

Tags: wpf, user-interface, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm building a WPF application which very simplified looks something like this:

[image: My WPF application]

I have an ApplicationView which holds the menu and a ContentControl.
The ContentControl binds to the property CurrentViewModel which is set by the menu and rendered by its related View (Views and ViewModels are coupled by DataTemplates defined in the App.xaml).

I found this approach on [Rachel Lim's blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

So in this example my View contains a list of duties as well as a "Details" window of the currently selected duty.

This setup works fine, but I think my ViewModels are getting too fat!
The non-simplified version of this ViewModel is up at around 500 lines of code, for handling:

- Initializing filters
- Logic for filtering list
- Displaying duty details
- Add/Update/Cancel/Delete logic

Now I'm very new to WPF but that seems like too much code, yea?
And it will be even bigger before I'm finished with it.

Anyways, I was thinking that I could split the ViewModel into two separate ViewModels; one for holding list and filters and one for showing the details. But how is this best accomplished?

I have thought of two approaches, but don't know which is preferable:

1. Create a DutyMasterView whose sole purpose is to hold two ContentControls for the actual Views (ie DutyListView and DutyDetailView each with their own ViewModel)?
   I'm using MVVM Light as my framework so I suppose I could use the messaging service to tell the DutyDetailViewModel which Duty to display, right?
   Alternately create a DutyMasterViewModel which exposes the selected duty.
2. Ditch the DutyMasterView and nest the DutyDetailView in the DutyListView.

Does it make sense to split my ViewModel into two or should I just stick with my fat ViewModel?
If splitting the ViewModel is recommended which of my suggestions makes most sense?
Are there other approaches that I should consider?

Comment: 500 lines is *not* a big file in my opinion.

Comment: Decide whatever is best for you. In my opinion ViewModels with more than 500 LOC tend to become hard to maintain.

Comment: If DutyDetailViewModel's only job is to display a duty, I don't see the point of using any messaging. Just update the property in the Master VM to return a different Detail VM.

Comment: Approach #3 - One super size VM splitted on 3 partial classes. :D joke

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for opinion, I'd do it almost like you mentioned in point 1 but you don't need any messaging.
You create two VMs. Let's say DutiesVM and DutyDetailVM. DutyDetailsVM contains just some string properties for ID and Name.
In DutiesVM you create two properties:

```
ObservableCollection<DutyDetailVM> DutiesList
DutyDetailVM SelectedDuty
```

Your DutiesView can look like this:

```
<DockPanel>
    <v:DutyDetailV DockPanel.Dock="Right" DataContext="{Binding SelectedDuty}">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DutiesList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDuty}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Now you can create ListView ItemTemplate that binds to DutyDetailVM Properties. 
 is usercontrol that defines the DutyDetail view. Selecting the item in the list updates the details control automatically.

That's just the sketch but I think you can get the point from it.